# Deeper fetch in nHibernate returns a proxy object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, proxy

I have the following data model that i'm trying to fetch using nHibernate.

Author -> List of AuthorBook -> Book

AuthorBook is basically a junction table that allows the many to many mappings between Author and Book.

Basically, I'm trying to come up with a query (using one session) that allows me
to pull the Author and the list of books that is associated with the author.

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
var author = session.QueryOver<Author>.Where(x => x.Id = AuthorId) 
                                      .Fetch(x => x.SomeList).Eager
                                      .Fetch(x => x.AuthorBooks).Eager
                                      .FutureValue();
```

That query will return the list of author books correctly, but the entities in list are proxy items (proxy author and proxy book). So i decided to do another fetch in the same session.

```
var authorBooks = session.QueryOver<AuthorBook>()
                         .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Author)
                         .Where(x => x.Id = AuthorId) 
                         .Fetch(x => x.Book).Eager
                         .Fetch(x => x.Author).Eager
                         .Future();
```

Then, i'll just set the result of the AuthorBooks to the main parent object ...

```
var actualAuthor = author.Value; //from the previous query
actualAuthor.AuthorBooks = new HashSet<AuthorBook>(authorBooks.ToList());
```

but that did not do the trick, it's still showing me that the records in AuthorBooks are proxy objects ... any thoughts on what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should fetch all your data in one go:

```
        AuthorBook authorBooks = null;
        Book book = null;

        session.QueryOver<Author>()
            .Where(x => x.Id = AuthorId)
            .JoinAlias(a => a.AuthorBooks, () => authorBooks,JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .JoinAlias(() => authorBooks.Book, () => book)
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I had to make both join alias left outer join to return a value, but otherwise this works as is. Thanks!